# Value showing issue in Datatable during changing the page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

In this table I am using datatable. For addition features I am using the checkboxes for show-hide the sgst,igst,cgst data. During first load igst and cgst data will be display automatically and click on sgst checkbox data will be show of sgst.
Issue:-
E.G. - Click on page-2 pagination menu, then click on sgst checkbox then click on 1 pagination menu then sgst value is not displaying.Same as alternate way.

Note: below for checkbox functionality

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
            var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
            $("." + inputValue).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
 <div class="checkbox-list">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
       <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox21" value="cgst" checked> CGST
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox22" value="igst"  checked> IGST
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox23" value="sgst"> SGST
    </label>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
    id="sample_1" style="text-align: center;">
    <thead>
        <tr class="head-grey">
            <th rowspan="2">CPIN</th>
            <th rowspan="2">CPIN Date & Time</th>
            <th rowspan="2">GSTIN</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Bank Code</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Mode of Payment</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Amount</th>
            <th colspan="5" scope="colgroup" class="cgst">CGST</th>
            <th colspan="5" scope="colgroup" class="igst">IGST</th>
            <th colspan="5" scope="colgroup" class="sgst">SGST</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="head-grey">
            <th class="cgst">Tax</th>
            <th class="cgst">Interest</th>
            <th class="cgst">Penalty</th>
            <th class="cgst">Fee</th>
            <th class="cgst">Others</th>
            <th class="igst">Tax</th>
            <th class="igst">Interest</th>
            <th class="igst">Penalty</th>
            <th class="igst">Fee</th>
            <th class="igst">Others</th>
            <th class="sgst">Tax</th>
            <th class="sgst">Interest</th>
            <th class="sgst">Penalty</th>
            <th class="sgst">Fee</th>
            <th class="sgst">Others</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="cgst">30,000</td>
            <td class="cgst">100,000</td>
            <td class="cgst">80,000</td>
            <td class="cgst">50,000</td>
            <td class="cgst">3555550,000</td>
            <td class="igst">100,000</td>
            <td class="igst">8,000</td>
            <td class="igst">50,000</td>
            <td class="igst">30,000</td>
            <td class="igst">50,000</td>
            <td class="sgst">50</td>
            <td class="sgst">30,000</td>
            <td class="sgst">100,000</td>
            <td class="sgst">80,000</td>
            <td class="sgst">50,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
            <td>F1</td>
            <td class="cgst">301,000</td>
            <td class="cgst">1055555555501,000</td>
            <td class="cgst">801,000</td>
            <td class="cgst">501,000</td>
            <td class="cgst">301,000</td>
            <td class="igst">1010,000</td>
            <td class="igst">81,000</td>
            <td class="igst">510,000</td>
            <td class="igst">310,000</td>
            <td class="igst">510,000</td>
            <td class="sgst">510</td>
            <td class="sgst">310,000</td>
            <td class="sgst">1010,000</td>
            <td class="sgst">810,000</td>
  <td class="sgst">510,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Any error you are getting in console?

Comment: No error in console.In that field in html layout display:none is showing when check html by f12. Have you run the table and understand the issue?

Comment: please copy fiddle code in your editor and run this, you will get the issue when click on sgst checkbox then go to the next page.Data will not show.         https://jsfiddle.net/aditi22/cpnc2ykz/3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value displaying issue in Datatable during pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538882/value-displaying-issue-in-datatable-during-pagination)

Comment: Another question in which you've re-asked your prior question. Please don't do this, it is a sure-fire way to get banned here.